# Splitting numpy array according bool

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have an array like

`a = np.array[ 4, 9, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 4, 2]`

and a boolean array (so that's a mask) of same size like

`boo = np.array[ True, True, False, False, True, True, True, False, True]`

(`boo` can also start with a `False` as first entry...)

Now I want to split `a` into new arrays with 2 conditions:

- a new sub array contains only values with `True` in `boo`
- a new sub array begins always after a `False` and ends before a `False`. 
  So a result would be `[[4, 9], [6, 4, 7], [2]]`

**My idea is:**
I know that I can use [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split) as basic. 
In this case it would be `b = np.split(a, [2, 4, 7, 8]` and afterwards I would only take eyery second element from `b`, starting with the first because my first element in `boo` is `True`.

So my problem is: How do I get the array `[2, 4, 7, 8]`?

(Looping with python is not an option, because it's too slow.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this is fast enough:

```
d = np.nonzero(boo != np.roll(boo, 1))[0]
if d[0] == 0:
    d = d[1:]
b = np.split(a, d)
b = b[0::2] if boo[0] else b[1::2]
```

---

Found a simpler and faster way:

```
indices = np.nonzero(boo[1:] != boo[:-1])[0] + 1
b = np.split(a, indices)
b = b[0::2] if boo[0] else b[1::2]
```

Comparing slices is at least twice as fast as `np.roll()` plus the if statement.
Also, `np.flatnonzero(...)` would look nicer than `np.nonzero(...)[0]` but be slightly slower.

Comment: Also also, instead of `boo[1:] != boo[:-1]` you can write `np.diff(boo)` :)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the best solution:

```
def splitByMask(a, mask):
    return numpy.split(a, numpy.flatnonzero(numpy.diff(mask)) + 1)
```

Results:

```
>>> myArray = numpy.array([4, 9, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 4, 2])
>>> myMask  = numpy.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]) # or True / False
>>> splitByMask(myArray, myMask)
[array([4, 9]), array([3, 1]), array([6, 4, 7]), array([4]), array([2])]
```

This also works for zero length arrays and for boolean masks.